# Server Side Google Analytics Client IP

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

I'm using the following:

- https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/seriously-simple-podcasting
- https://github.com/dancameron/server-side-google-analytics

I'm using wordpress action hooks that the plugin provides to use the ss-ga class that triggers a page hit for the XML Feed (iTunes needs this) and event for the podcast play (download):

`ssp_file_download` and `ssp_before_feed`

That all works great.  I'm using cloudflare, so I can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` OR `$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]` to get the client IP. The problem, is that with ss-ga, I cannot send the client IP when registering the event or page hit.  As a result, it always shows Chicago, which is where my host's data center is.

Can someone suggest a way to make sure that when I send an analytics event using a php class, that the IP is correct?

Thanks in advance.  If you want any code, just let me know but I've used basic examples as provided by both script's documentation.

Cheers.

Comment: The way I was using ssga I was generating a GIF url which I was displaying in the page. Then from that Google would get the user IP. Is that what you do?

Comment: It's all happening server-side. There is no output to any page.  That's part of my issue.

Comment: I guess you could request the GIF server-side with Curl and manually set the IP based on $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].

Comment: Ok. I'd love to see exactly how you suggest I do this.  The ss-ga class doesn't allow for IP override.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to override the IP via the ss-ga class. You can simply set it with Curl. You basically simulate a request to the GIF as if it was coming from the user's browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the best way would be not the ss-ga class and instead use the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en). The measurement protocol is not only the way Google Analytics should be implemented these days, it also [offers a parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=en#uip) `&uip` to send an users IP along. There are [various](https://github.com/theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol) [packages](https://github.com/ins0/google-measurement-php-client) [that](https://github.com/krizon/php-ga-measurement-protocol) [implement](https://packagist.org/search/?q=moriony%2Fphp-ga-measurement-protocol&reason=package_not_found) the measurement protocol in PHP classes, so it should't be harder to use than ss-ga (in fact it's most probably simpler, more reliable and better documented since it is specifially built to provide a language agnostic interface to GA).

Comment: This was it, and for some reason it eluded me.  Thanks so much! It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try if to generate the GIF URL using `getFullBeaconUrl()`, then request this GIF via Curl, and set the IP to the user's IP. Something like that should work:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $gifUrl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ip", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip"));
```

Comment: I appreciate your time. I ended up using the solution from @Eike Pierstorff.  Thanks!